# windows 10 command-line run python with multiple dot file fail

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a problem.
if I run in my windows 10 command line it will fail:

```
py -2 -m "test1.1.py"
```

error msg: `No module named. test1.1`

looks like the command line can not recognize my two-dot file.  If I rename the python to test1.py it will work. Any idea how to fix it without change the python names? 
Thanks

Comment: It is better to rename the file into test1_1.py. Module names do not allow dot to be part of them. Or you can run the file using py test1.1.py as a standalone python file rather than a module

Answer (score 4):

Module names with a dot is not allowed in python. The dot is reserved for accessing attributes, as in `module.function` or `obj.attribute`.

You can still run a python file with a dot in the name, but not the way you're trying, by loading as a module. Try `py -2 test1.1.py`, but I whould suggest renaming the file `test1_1.py`.